# htaccess not working as required

Tags: .htaccess

I cannot get my .htaccess file working properly. Please can someone help me correct it.

I used http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to try and get it correct, but with no success.

http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/rolex-watch.php
should show in the address bar as 
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/rolex-watch
and show the rolex-watch.php page

http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/products.php?f=Watch&b=Tissot&t=T-Touch
should show in the address bar as 
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/products/Watch/Tissot/T-Touch
and show the products page with f and optional parameters b and t parameters set.

**.htaccess File contents**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /bootstrap/404.php   
ErrorDocument 403 /bootstrap/403.php 

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/products/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ bootstrap/products.php?f=$4&b=$5&t=$6
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/products/(.*)/(.*)$ bootstrap/products.php?f=$4&b=$5
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/products/(.*)$ bootstrap/products.php?f=$4
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/products/search/(.*)$ bootstrap/products.php?s=$1

Redirect bootstrap/rolex-watch.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/rolex-watch
Redirect bootstrap/scrap-gold.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/scrap-gold
Redirect bootstrap/eternity-ring.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/eternity-ring
Redirect bootstrap/engagement-ring.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/engagement-    ring
Redirect bootstrap/wedding-ring.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/wedding-ring
Redirect bootstrap/diamond-ring.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/diamond-ring
Redirect bootstrap/inferno-diamonds.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/inferno-    diamonds
Redirect bootstrap/radley-products.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/radley-products

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jon Lin, but it didn't quite work for me.

I seem to have bluffed my way to something that does work. Some entries I didn't need.

Is it written efficiently as I have no options defined?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /bootstrap/

ErrorDocument 404 /bootstrap/404.php   
ErrorDocument 403 /bootstrap/403.php 

RewriteRule ^products/search/(.*)$ products.php?s=$1
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ products.php?f=$1&b=$2&t=$3
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)$ products.php?f=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ products.php?f=$1

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have some stray spaces in your mod_alias `Redirect` directives:

```
Redirect bootstrap/engagement-ring.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/engagement-    ring

Redirect bootstrap/inferno-diamonds.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/inferno-    diamonds
```

These will cause a 500 server error, because it has the incorrect 3 parameters.

Secondly, your `Redirect` directives need to match against a leading `/`, so they all need to look like:

```
Redirect /bootstrap/rolex-watch.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/rolex-watch
```

But those 2 issues are really just moot because you've created a redirect loop by rewriting the URI with your last rule, and redirecting *again* via the `Redirect` statements. The two different modules that you are using, mod_alias (`Redirect`) and mod_rewrite (`Rewrite*`) both get applied to the same URI at different point in the URI processing pipeline, and thus they both mangle the same URI. You need to stick with just mod_rewrite and add a check at the very beginning to prevent looping altogether:

```
# This prevents the rules from looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^bootstrap/products/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ bootstrap/products.php?f=$4&b=$5&t=$6
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/products/(.*)/(.*)$ bootstrap/products.php?f=$4&b=$5
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/products/(.*)$ bootstrap/products.php?f=$4
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/products/search/(.*)$ bootstrap/products.php?s=$1

RewriteRule ^bootstrap/rolex-watch.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/rolex-watch [L]
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/scrap-gold.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/scrap-gold [L]
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/eternity-ring.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/eternity-ring [L]
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/engagement-ring.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/engagement-ring [L]
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/wedding-ring.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/wedding-ring [L]
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/diamond-ring.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/diamond-ring [L]
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/inferno-diamonds.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/inferno-diamonds [L]
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/radley-products.php http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bootstrap/radley-products [L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```